# 100C CPU temperature in Ubuntu's "sensors", but 39C in BIOS, which one is correct?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cpu, temperature, sensors

I have MSI x470 gaming motherboard and AMD Ryzen 2600x and running Ubuntu 18.04.

The issue is, when I type `sensors` in the terminal it gives me output on CPU temperature to be 90-108° C (only browsing the internet, a few tabs opened), but when I quickly reboot the PC and open the BIOS, it says CPU temperature is 37°-39° and the motherboard temperature is 37°.

I doubt that in less than a minute it can cool down from 100° to 39°. Unfortunately the motherboard reports only CPU and motherboard temperature, so no luck to check other sensors.

Can there be some sort of misreading in CPU temperature sensors while using the `sensors` software command? Or can the CPU chip itself really be this hot under the cooler?

Comment: Very likely a scaling factor is wrong. Read the lmsensors documentation, IIRC it has a description how to calibrate and deal with that (using a config file).